# nodejs md5 with base64 digest algorithm wrong result

Tags: node.js, base64, md5

here is my code

```
var sig = crypto.createHash('md5')
  .update('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')
  .digest('base64');
console.log(sig)
```

results in `nhB9nTcrtoJr2B01QqQZ1g==` (on Mac OS X).

I'm trying to generate the same signature from an ios app. The results are the same in objective c as in online converter sites: **the string**

`The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`

converted to **md5**, I get 
`9e107d9d372bb6826bd81d3542a419d6`,

and the **base64** of this is `OWUxMDdkOWQzNzJiYjY4MjZiZDgxZDM1NDJhNDE5ZDY=`.

Why are those strings different? Isn't this what nodejs crypto module is doing?
What are the equivalent of nodejs algorithm for getting the md5 hash digested with base64?

Comment: Just so I'm sure I understand the question. Do you want the md5 hash of the string 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog' encoded into base64 or do you want the string it self converted into base64?

Comment: @ThomasWatson, I want the base64 encoded string of the md5 hash of the `The quick brown fox..`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The string `OWUxMDdkOWQzNzJiYjY4MjZiZDgxZDM1NDJhNDE5ZDY=` is the base64 encoded version of the string `9e107d9d372bb6826bd81d3542a419d6` which is in it self the md5 hash of the plain text string `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`.

If you want to do this in node you first have to get the md5 hash in hex:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var s = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
var md5 = crypto.createHash('md5').update(s).digest('hex');
```

Now you have the md5 hash as hex (`9e107d9d372bb6826bd81d3542a419d6`). Now all you have to do is convert it to base64:

```
new Buffer(md5).toString('base64');
```

Comment: Can't you just use `.digest().toString('base64')`? BTW you'd need `new Buffer(md5, 'hex')` for this to work properly, now you're getting base64 of hex digest, not of the original binary hash.