# Node.js MD5 generates different result than htpasswd -m

Tags: node.js

when generating a password file using `htpasswd -m -c file admin` with the password `admin` the result looks like this:

```
cat file  
admin:$apr1$V.aqW878$JCj8ivmSnFp3BnTCtLAuN.
```

When I try to authenticate against that using node.js the results are rather different:

```
Digest Hex: 21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3
```

I've tried following [this existing StackOverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388745/nodejs-md5-with-base64-digest-algorithm-wrong-result):

```
new Buffer('21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3').toString('base64');
MjEyMzJmMjk3YTU3YTVhNzQzODk0YTBlNGE4MDFmYzM=
```

So the result was still wrong.

When I change the digest to `base64` the result would be:

```
ISMvKXpXpadDiUoOSoAfww==
```

Bottom line of my problem is that I don't get the same hashes and need help. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you
Roman

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I found the answer. htpasswd uses a "salt" which is stored in the middle bit of the password string:

```
$apr1$V.aqW878$JCj8ivmSnFp3BnTCtLAuN.
Salt: V.aqW878
```

The [node-pass module](https://github.com/andris9/pass/blob/master/pass.js) gave me the right clues. See `validate_md5`. It uses the native openssl command to generate a salted MD5 hash.

In retrospect this makes sense since MD5 isn't safe anymore. That's the reason I didn't use it for years now and got a bit off track here. In essence, anything marked with `$apr1$` is to be treated like this.